# How can I raise error from IIS in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, timer, webforms

When I run my application in Visual Studio. The Application doesn't "break". I have a Timer in a library project that sends emails. This timer is called every 30000.0. I call a method within this timer that have a long logic. This method works fine when I am in Visual Studio. The problem is when I move my application to IIS. This causes the following error:

```
 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Subproceso anulado.
   en lktec.Sql.SMail.Send()
   en lktec.Sql.SAutoRun.SendMailSchedule(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Somethimes I get a similar error :

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Subproceso anulado.
   en SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SNI_ConnWrapper* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
   en SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   en System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   en System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   en System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   en lktec.Sql.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(String connectionString, String cmdText, SqlParameter[] paras)
   en lktec.Sql.SEdmMailRunLogsLevel2.GetItem4(Int32 paramSysNo)
   en lktec.Sql.SAutoRun.SendMailSchedule(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

So, the thing I am having problem is why in Visual Studio I am not getting this error? How can I make Visual Studio raise this error? I have added try-catch and this doesn't do nothing. I also added steps to write into a file to know where it breaks the timer tread. It breaks at the point where it specified in the error. But how can I "fix" this in visual studio if is not raised at all? This only happen in IIS.

How the method work:

SendMailSchedule()

This method call the SQL Server and obtain several information (Select statements: 7 calls independantly) then it does Insert and Update to the Sql Server to different tables.

When method is called it gets a list of validEmail that are in a scheduler. The it goes trough a loop and within this loop it gets the current information (trigger). Then it gets a list of all the Run information that shares Id of the trigger.Then it retrive a list of valid schedule information. This information is different from scheduler.

Then it goes to a inner loop for the Run information list. At this loop validates the crontab string specified in the  scheduler information. If crontab string matches; it processed to validate if start time with run start time value. When it is validated it goes into a while loop. this loop will be always true until the Run is completed.

Within the while loop; it gets a list of Detail Run info. This is kinda like a level 2 for Run Info. Here it goes into another inner loop. At this point, it validates Level 2 start time and it matches it gets into another inner loop that goes through an email list. In this loop; it also does gather information for updating the table, inserting historical log of the steps, and sends emails.

Structure of the Method:

```
Foreach (...)
{
   Foreach (...) [This will go through a daily once]
   {
     While(true)
     {
       Foreach(...)  [This will go through a list each Hourly until 20th hour it while to false]
       {
         Foreach(...) [Here is a list of email Loop]
         {
            SendEmail 
         }
       }
     }  
   }
}
```

Like I said, this method works fine with Visual Studio but it doesn't work with IIS. Is there a way to raise the error in visual studio?

Comment: What does 'Subproceso anulado' mean? Subprocess unloaded? Is this a multi-threading applicatiion? Show some real code please.

Comment: Hi 'Subproceso anulado = Thread aborted. Sorry, it is in spanish the error. forgot to translate it. It uses a timer as a thread. I have mutiple timers running at the same time. This is in a dll that I call from my webform

Comment: So yes its a multithreaded application. With multithreading it is always about guarding the objects that are accessed by more than 1 thread. Ask yourself, why did the thread abort. Did some object get removed by the Garbarge Collector? Did I guard all the object that are accessed by more than 1 thread? Multithreading programming is pretty difficult if you don't follow best practices.

Comment: But really. To get an answer you need to add more of your code.

Comment: Web forms is poorly suited to using timers and threads for too many reasons to go into in a comment. Background operations should be taken out of IIS

Comment: The problem is that the code is very long and people keep telling me releated code. But the method is like 400 lines plus the timer call which is 5 lines. Do you still need the code?

Comment: @Crowcoder- Hi I use timer is a dll which is stored in the Bin folder of the webform application.  I am confuse why using visual studio i dont get any error. But when I use IIS i get the error.

Comment: You are doing exactly the bad things a web app on IIS should avoid, https://blog.lextudio.com/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a And running it on VS hides all kinds of differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: i was checking the IIS configuration application pool and I notice that it has a 20 min time out for the "idle-timeout" and it is on demand for the  "start Mode". I will change the setup to be always on as  Lex Li suggested.  Hopefully this will not cause the timer to teminate.